# How to extract specific text from a large text content?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have one paragraph

```
Dear testUser testUser, 
You have been registered in the Request Management System. 
Your username is the email address to which this notification is addressed. 
Please click the link below to set your password: http://www.example.com/QA/ChangePassword.aspx?userName=example@yopmail.com&tempPassword=b0cb6ca7-2e52-4b80-8252-f5dac499cea3
You will receive further information from the our employee that has registered you in the system.
Thank you
```

In above paragraph i want to extract the URL which is the one which is of use to generate new password.

I used regular expression for this and I am able to achieve it some what.

Below is the code i used

```
String REGEX="Dear testuser,testuser,|You have been registered in the Request Management System.|Your username is the email address to which this notification is addressed.|Please click the link below to set your password:|You will receive further information from the our employee that has registered you in the system.|Thank you";
       if(copiedText.contains("password"))
                    {
                        copiedText=copiedText.replaceAll(REGEX, "").trim();
                        System.out.println("Final Text after replace: "+copiedText);
                        keyValues.put(key,copiedText);
                        System.out.println("the Values stored in map are:" + keyValues);

                    }
```

I am getting the URL using this but i consider this as not a good approach. I need some generic solution as username is also going to change in real time scenario. So how we can handle this in java.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you need.  If it's working but you feel it's not a good approach, please let us know what your requirements are for a good approach.  As for handling different users: look over [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), which will show you how to use _character classes_ to match sequences of letters (or sequences of other types of characters).

Comment: I want to handle different usernames if possible using some regular expressions.

Comment: Can you post your regex? Also what is 'key' here?

Comment: If the text before and after the required URL is a constant, why not go for a substring ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `spit string`

```
String expe= "Dear testUser testUser,"
            + "You have been registered in the Request Management System. "
            + "Your username is the email address to which this notification is addressed. "
            + "Please click the link below to set your password: http://www.example.com/QA/ChangePassword.aspx?userName=example@yopmail.com&tempPassword=b0cb6ca7-2e52-4b80-8252-f5dac499cea3"
            + "You will receive further information from the our employee that has registered you in the system."
            + "Thank you";


        String[] parts = expe.split("your password: ");
        String part2 = parts[1]; 
        parts = part2.split("You will receive further information");
        part2 = parts[0]; 
        System.out.println(part2);
```

You will get the required URL easily.

Comment: Yes we can use this one as well.